# Aspect Ratio for Circle in ImageCropper

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an app which requires crop image to set aspect ratio of profile picture . Right now I have set aspect ratio to (1,1) but it is Square . I want a circle cropped image, So please help me to find out what should be the aspect ratio for circle. 
I am using a An Open Source Image Cropper |
Link for Documentation :[HERE](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)
Keywords; Android Programming, App developer, Android Studio

```
CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't crop an image to be a circle. Images must be rectangular. What you could do is manually cut out a circle and make the rest transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `setCropShape()` method of `ActivityBuilder`

```
CropImage.activity(imageUri)
         .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
         ...
         .start(this);
```